# Respond to hotkey from another application

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm working on an Windows application in C++ which needs to respond to keyboard hot-key from another application. For example, given application A is the one I'm coding and application B is the one I wish to monitory for the hot-key event. Suppose that the hot-key event is when a user presses the key combination <CTRL>+/ while inside application B. I've tried to use the RegisterHotKey in my Application A code using the handle to Application B, but that does work. How do I get Application A to monitor Application B for the hot-key event?

Comment: Sounds like you may need to make use of the `SetWindowsHookEx` function, using an _idHook_ parameter equal to `WH_KEYBOARD`.

Comment: Re: above comment: Actually, this appears not to work for processes other than the current process. Perhaps you need to examine Global Hook techniques. :)

Comment: Using `SetWindowsHookEx()` to hook another process, you need to implement the hook inside of a DLL, then you can set the ThreadID parameter to either 0 to hook all processes, or the ThreadID of the window you are trying to hook (look at [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx)).  Otherwise, use [`SetWinEventHook()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) instead of `SetWindowsHookEx()`, as it is safer and easier to use.